# Is it OK to take a disposable safety razor on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

I'm travelling soon with cabin luggage only and I was wondering if I can take a disposable safety razor with me?

[This page](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Foreigntravel/AirTravel/DG_176922) says it's OK, but it also says it's OK to take small scissors and I've definitely seen them confiscated.

Comment: It might depend on the airline and whether it's a domestic or international flight if you want to include those details.

Comment: It definitely has nothing to do with an airline. It's an airport security question/practice. And we don't have domestic flights over here ;)

Comment: You live in a country so small there's only one airport but so secret you don't want to tell me or so obvious I should be able to smell it over the Internet? (-:

Comment: In Singapore, small scissors and razor usually confiscated by the security.

Comment: @hippietrail: I live in Lithuania. You can discover this by clicking on my name ;) There are 3 airports (or so) but the country is small enough that no one flies between these 3 airports.

Comment: @Alan: So much clicking (-; Sorry I'm hitchhiking around the world right now and don't always find stable connections. As for your question, I've heard stories where even the tiny nail file in a set of nail clippers has been snapped off in Australia so it seems to vary depending on how hyped up they are about terrorists or how officious they are being, as well as which country and airport.

Comment: What can a hijacker do with a disposable razor anyway: threaten to give the pilots a shave?

Comment: to prevent macgyver-wannabe hijacker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on the security measures of your departure airport.

For example:

1. [Singapore Changi Airport](http://www.changiairport.com/passenger-guide/safety-and-security/travel-tips-for-departure)

   All types of razor are prohibited.

   > Therefore, passengers should not have any sharp objects with them or
   >   in their hand-carried baggage (for example pocket knives, nail files,
   >   box cutters, razors, scissors, corkscrews, any sharp/pointed objects,
   >   etc.)
2. [Heathrow](http://www.lifeatheathrow.com/heathrow-security.html)

   Plastic moulded razors are allowed, but razors that can be opened and razors with changeable blades are prohibited. I assume disposable razor = plastic moulded razor.

   > Razors that have the blade set into a plastic moulding are allowed,
   >   but razors that can be opened and the razor blade removed are
   >   prohibited
3. [Airport in US](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm)

   Disposable Razors (including razor with removable razor blades/catridges) are permitted.
   I believe the scissors you mentioned have length > than 4 inches, that's why it was confiscated.

   > Scissors - metal with pointed tips and blades shorter than four inches are permitted.
   >   Razor-Type Blades - such as box cutters, utility knives, and safety razor blades are not permitted. (disposable razors and their cartridges are permitted)

   My advice is to check the security section of your departure airport's website.

Answer (score 7):

I think this depends on luck. There have been people who passed with a small knife. Sometimes I passed with safety pin - they didn't detect it somehow (but it was visible on my trousers). Sometimes they didn't let me pass with film roll. Depends on whether they detect it or not.

Answer (score 5):

You are usually able to buy razors on the other side of security in the shops in the airport you travel to, so even if they take your razors, you can buy some new ones.

Comment: Sure, but 1) that's a solution, not an answer ;) 2) I haven't seen disposable razors sold by 1 piece. Buying and throwing away 2-3 is a total waste.

Comment: @AlanMendelevich You can use the other two or three another time.  Anyway, who is concerned about waste when they are about to hijack an airplane?

Answer (score 4):

So, I've traveled through 4 airports: Vilnius, Frankfurt, Vienna and Sofia. Razor wasn't a problem in any of them. I've seen a lady with small scissors in Sofia's airport and the security guy said it was OK.