# Gillette shaver on board?

Tags: ryanair, prohibited-items

is there any chance I might get problems because of taking Gillette shaver (razor blade version) on board? I mean, I could not find it in prohibited items list, but it still cuts you know...

Specifically I am going to travel via Ryanair this time, any chance they will not let me take it with me?

Comment: You mean an electric shaver?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus No, I mean the one with razor blades. Is it even possible to CUT with electric one? I will edit the post.

Comment: Do you mean a safety razor with a cartridge system, or one with a naked blade?

Comment: I had no problems entering with it through security control recently. Now, I only got that shaver because my plane was delayed and I had to stay overnight in a  hotel without having access to my baggage. The next morning I took home the free of charge shaver, toothbrush, night dress, etc.

Comment: Can you perhaps include a picture of the type of shaver you are talking about?  Gillette has many kinds of products.

Comment: General knowledge, I can not find proof right now, is that the shavers with the 4cm blades fixed in the head are allowed. If you do not mind losing it, shuch it in the bin to go through the scanner, with your coins and such, and ask the guys there.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/is-it-ok-to-take-a-disposable-safety-razor-on-a-plane

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After posting the TSA information below, I noticed the [ryanair](/questions/tagged/ryanair) tag.  Here's what they have to say about sharp objects, emphasis added:

> 8.10.1.2 Pointed/edged Weapons & Sharp Objects; pointed or bladed articles capable of causing injury, including axes & hatchets, cleavers, arrows and darts, crampons (grappling iron, hooked bar of iron, or plate with iron spikes used in mountaineering), harpoons & spears, ice axes & ice picks, ice skates, knives with blades of more than 6 cms including lockable or flick knives, ceremonial, religious and hunting knives, made of metal or any other material strong enough to be used as a potential weapon, meat cleavers, machetes, ***open razors and blades (excluding safety or disposable razors with blades enclosed in cartridge),*** sabres, swords and swordsticks, scalpels, scissors with blades more than 6 cms as measured from the fulcrum, ski and walking/hiking poles, throwing stars, tradesman's tools with a blade or a shaft of more than 6 cms that have the potential to be used as a pointed or edged weapon, e.g.drills and drill bits, box cutters, utility knives, all saws, screwdrivers, chisels, crowbars, hammers, pliers, wrenches/spanners, blow torches.

Source: https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/

---

I'll leave the TSA information in the answer to show that the basic approach is quite consistent from one country to the next.

According to the TSA, in carry-on luggage, you can bring

- Disposable razors
- Cartridge-type safety razor blades
- Non-cartridge safety razors without blades

You cannot bring non-cartridge disposable razor blades in the cabin, but they can be in your checked bags.

Source: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items

Other transportation safety authorities have similar rules.  I once traveled from Europe to the US with a non-cartridge safety razor in my carry-on bag, but I left the blades behind because I did not want to check any luggage.

Comment: I wonder how they tell a hiking pole from a cane? Stylish seniors of my acquaintance prefer the former.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus presumably it depends on the sharpness of the point, since the context is the prohibition of objects that can be used as weapons, and the paragraph is the one concerning "pointed/edged weapons and sharp objects."

Answer (score 2):

In business class, they have those shavers in the bathrooms. Anyone can grab one there during the flight, so they are obviously allowed and considered save.

Comment: In whose business class? Ryanair?

Comment: no, but different others (United, Lufthansa, Delta, American, US Airways). My point is that it is common to have them around on flights, so they are generally allowed and considered save. And the security checkpoint doesn't know you fly Ryan Air - they do not apply separate rules per airline.